# Jquery hover method behaves strangely

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseover, jquery-hover, mouseenter

```
$(".panel-top").hover(rollOut, hideStatus);

function rollOut() {
    $(".panel-top").css("width", "100px").on("transitionend", showStatus);
}

function showStatus() {
    $(".panel-top-status").css("opacity", "1");
}


function rollIn() {
    $(".panel-top").css("width", "20px");
}

function hideStatus() {
    $(".panel-top-status").css("opacity", "0").on("transitionend", rollIn);
}
```

Above is the the code that I have been playing around for hours now. I need the `.panel-top` to unroll when I hover over it. When it finishes unrolling, the `.panel-top-status` should become visible. It is located on the top-panel. This part works fine.
When I remove the mouse from the top-panel, it folds down as expected. The status also fades away, but it reappears again almost instantaneously. 
I tried different methods - mouseover, mouseenter, mouseout, mouseleave. All of them have different bugs. The `hover` method is working best so far, but it still has this one bug. 
Here is the link to my [codepen](http://codepen.io/khier996/pen/xgqqEL). 
What am I doing wrong? Please help...

Comment: Show us your relevant html and css code

Comment: create a fiddle or add script of your working code and add in your question.

Comment: Show your html and css code.So that it will be usefull for others to help you

Comment: I think putting all of the html and css here would be too much. So, I created a codepen. Here is the [link](http://codepen.io/khier996/pen/xgqqEL). The part I am having problems with is at the bottom of javascript section. Guys, thanks for taking your time to help me. This is my first time posting a question in stackoverflow. Hope you can help me